# Canonical answer for "x/0"?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Does a canonical answer exist for the question of $\frac{x}{0}$ that covers all the popular misunderstandings and problems?

Can [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0) be considered the canonical reference?

Comment: If canonical means "covers all the popular misunderstandings and problems," I don't know how we can be sure, but we could always add something if it isn't there.  "Canonical" in what context?  The linked question is referring to elementary arithmetic.  Although at least one of the answers mentions limits, I don't see any that mention that e.g. $\frac10=\infty$ is a useful convention in some contexts.

Comment: While it might be nice to have a place to gather all the possible answers to the various versions of this, I feel that the mentioned question is simply of too poor quality to be the right place for it (containing such phrases as "0/0 is Undefined and has infinite solutions").